# Is there a quicker way to rename bookmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, bookmark+

Is there a quicker way to rename bookmarks?

When I hit <kbd>r</kbd> in the *Bookmark List*, `bmkp-bmenu-edit-bookmark-name-and-location` asks me for the new name, but it also asks me for a new location, which is something I don't want to answer every time, cause it's the same location.

It also asks me to save the changes when I've done that, which I also don't want to be prompted for.

Comment: I usually open bookmark file and edit it there

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities:

1. When `r` asks for the bookmark location (target) you can just use `RET` to get the default value (no location change). IOW, rename the bookmark, then hit `RET`.
2. If you don't want to do even that (hit `RET`) then you can bind `r` (or any other key) to the *vanilla* Emacs command `bookmark-bmenu-rename`.  It doesn't let you (ands so doesn't ask you to) relocate the target.
3. `C-u r` or `e` lets you edit the *full* bookmark -- any of its data, without having to edit your bookmark file directly, searching for the bookmark, etc. After changing whatever you want to change (e.g., just the bookmark name), use `C-c C-c` to save your changes.